# Magento 1.9.0.1 keeps log me out from admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, magento1.9.0.1

My magento admin loading unexpectedly slow. Though I am able to work but sometimes when we try to load ajax request, it gets expired and kicks user out from magento login.

Here's a error we got from console,

```
{"ajaxExpired":1,"ajaxRedirect":"https://xxxxx/index/login /key/18f7fc56cc065d0e2bb21f091ad1ac14/"}
```

For example, When I try to upload or insert image through WYSIWYG editor, Due to slow admin, it is taking too much time for processing AJAX request. so Ajax request is getting expired and kicks user out(log me out)from admin.

Can anyone help me to resolve it? Help Appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There might be some caching issue on your side. Someone my change core file "**config.php**" to turn off the cache. Because of that it takes time to load page, images and data.

I suggest you to track your file and if any changes have been made in that file then please revert it back. It's not appropriate solution of anything by changing in core files. In addition, check your server setting for **redis cache** and **gzip compression**.

I hope this information may help you.

Thanks